# Is there a way to make Nano support auto-complete and auto-bracket closing?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, text-editing, autocomplete, nano

Does anyone know if there's a way to make nano support auto-complete and auto-bracket closing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just downloaded and perused the source of Nano with some grepping. I can say with 95% confidence that Nano doesn't support auto-bracket or auto-complete.

Meta-] will jump to the matching bracket under the cursor though.

Sorry!

Comment: Oh.. that's alright. Thanks for your time. Just one quick question though: What do you mean by Meta-]?

Comment: Meta, in *nix is usually a single-tap of Esc or holding down Alt. Try this: put your cursor on a bracket then hold down alt and push ']'.  Alternatively, you can just press esc and then press ].  This depends on how your terminal and/or terminal emulator are set up.

Either way, once you do the sequence, nano will jump to the next matching bracket.

Comment: Note to new visitors: this answer is deprecated. See other answer below.

Answer (score 15):

As of at least Nano 2.9.8, autocompletion is supported.

Pressing `^]` (`C-]`) will check for words beginning with the current prefix in the current buffer and grab the first one. Pressing `^]` multiple times will cycle through the available matches. Regardless of how many times `^]` is pressed consecutively, `^[u` (`M-u`) will undo all of them as a unit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to spend some time trying setting things up, there is a modded nano version that works with autocompletion: https://github.com/orsonteodoro/nano-ycmd

However, your safest bet is probably [micro](https://micro-editor.github.io/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).